# How to call 2d arrays int data to a text label?

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract an array value in C# WPF Environment. I have a 2D array as var.

I've tried calling the array directly to a text label and it shows as
"<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String][]"

Here's how my 2d array looked like

```
            var iitems = new[] {
                new { Text = "HSKL", Value = "7149191" },
                new { Text = "VKL", Value = "7149192" }, 
            };

            comboBox1.DataSource = iitems;
```

and here's how i try to call them.

```
            string ivitems = comboBox1.DataSource.ToString();
            hsklTotal.Text = ivitems;
```

I wanted to only extract the Value of my array and i believe i am doing something wrong here. How do i proceed?

Comment: So which value do you want to extract?

Comment: Either 7149191 or 7149192.

I actually have 10 more list to fill in the array. So i guess by solving 1 , i will be able to extract the others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get "7149191" you can do

```
dynamic[] items = (dynamic[])comboBox1.DataSource;
hsklTotal.Text = items[0].Value;
```

Comment: THANKS! This actually worked with my full code.

I actually have a datagridview running.

i used the Value to determine which Rows will be filtered on my dataset.

Previously this is my code.

``
((DataTable)dataGridView3.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = "serialno = " + ivProperty;
``
Where ivProperty = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();

So based on your line , i added the Dynamic line outside of my try,catch sequence , and replaced ivProperty with items[0].Value.

This works extremely well. 

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the value in the line below, rather ToString implementation of your anonymous type

```
string ivitems = comboBox1.DataSource.ToString();
```

You should use this:

```
iitems[0].Value
```

Comment: Hi , yes , but i also need to add a variable called dynamic before i can use iitems[0].value.

Thanks you for the answer! :)

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin dynamic is not a variable and please understand that there is a cost associated with using it. If you are trying to access the list outside the method where you created it then I would say please create a proper object and not an anonymous type